# Python- splitting a csv file into different dataframes according to date or time interval

Tags: python, pandas

I have imported a csv file into python. It has readings at 5 min intervals over a period of a month. There are about 250 readings per 5 min timestamp. Below is a sample of one row per timestamp. Is there a way to split the csv into different dataframes grouped by date or even 5 min interval for plotting purposes? Like i mentioned, this dataset has 250 readings per 5 min interval for a month so I would like to do this without having to hard code each dataframe for each day or each interval in the set.

```
df.head()

    tmc_code   measurement_tstamp     ...         miles  road_order
0  112-05650  2018-05-01 00:00:00     ...      0.427814       768.0
1  112-05650  2018-05-01 00:05:00     ...      0.427814       768.0
2  112-05650  2018-05-01 00:10:00     ...      0.427814       768.0
3  112-05650  2018-05-01 00:15:00     ...      0.427814       768.0
4  112-05650  2018-05-01 00:20:00     ...      0.427814       768.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What it sounds like to me is that you want a new DataFrame for each date. If that is what you desire, the following code will take your dataframe, and make a list of dataframes, each which will only contain data for one date.

```
df.measurement_tstamp = df.measurement_tstamp.str[:10]
l = df.measurement_tstamp.unique()
data = [df.loc[df['measurement_tstamp']==i] for i in l]
```

## Edit

If you want to do it by 5 min interval, it's even simpler!

```
data = [df.loc[df['measurement_tstamp']==i] for i in df.measurement_tstamp.unique()]
```

That should do it

Comment: That worked!! Thank you so much! Would you mind showing me how to adjust that code to separate the dataframes for each 5 min interval as well?